# Matplotlib: Scatter Plot to Foreground on top of a Contour Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Does anyone know a way to bring a scatter plot to the foreground in matplotlib? I have to display the scatter plotting on top of the contour, but by default it is plotted underneath...

Comment: Check out the [`zorder`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_zorder) parameter of the `scatter` method. [Example usage](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html) from the matplotlib site.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can manually choose in which order the different plots are to be displayed with the [`zorder`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_zorder) parameter of e.g. the `scatter` method.

To demonstrate, see the code below, where the scatter plot in the left subplot has `zorder=1` and in the right subplot it has `zorder=-1`. The object with the highest `zorder` is placed on top. This means that the scatter will be placed on top of the contour in the first subplot, while it is placed underneath in the second subplot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)

norm = cm.colors.Normalize(vmax=abs(Z).max(), vmin=-abs(Z).max())
cmap = cm.PRGn

levels = np.arange(-2.0, 1.601, 0.4)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, sharey=True)

for ax, zord in zip(axes, [1, -1]):
    ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels,
                cmap=cm.get_cmap(cmap, len(levels)-1),
                norm=norm)
    ax.autoscale(False) # To avoid that the scatter changes limits
    ax.scatter(np.random.uniform(-3,3,10),
               np.random.uniform(-2,2,10),
               zorder=zord)
    ax.set_title('Scatter with zorder={0}'.format(zord))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What's missing is the reference point for zorder. What are the default zorder values for different plot functions?

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś The default values are described on [this page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html). Filled contours are "patches" and have default zorder `1`, while scatter plots are "collections" and also have default zorder `1`. The OP probably called `contourf` *after* calling `scatter` -- when zorders are identical they are plotted in the order in which they were created.