# matplotlib's contour function modifying previous plot?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, plot, octave

I'm converting some simple octave/matlab programs into python, but in using matplotlib's `contour` function, previously plotted 2D points all seem to align or flatten onto x=1. Any ideas why this is happening?

[image: matplotlib's contour "pushes" dots to x=1...]

For a logistic regression exercise, in octave/matlab I plot some data points

```
plotData(X(:,2:3), y);
```

and then show the decision boundary around different categories. This last part is done with `contour`:

```
contour(u, v, z, [0, 0], 'LineWidth', 2)
```

The result is this:

[image: octave/matlab's proper contour result]

In python, everything goes well plotting points:

```
p1 = plt.plot(X[pos,0], X[pos,1], marker='+', markersize=9, color='k')[0]
p2 = plt.plot(X[neg,0], X[neg,1], marker='o', markersize=7, color='y')[0]
```

[image: properly plotted data points]

but when then immediately after using `contour` as below, the first image is output:

```
p3 = plt.contour(u, v, z, levels=[0], linewidth=2)
```

As a note, `u` and `v` are identical in octave/matlab and python, both created with `linspace(-1, 1.5, 50)` (python notation). I've even taken care manually to ensure that the python `z` array is identical in python to the octave/matlab `z` matrix to see if the values were affecting this behavior.

A few different google searches haven't yielded much and I haven't spotted anything in the [python](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contour) or [matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) `contour` documentation. Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

**Update**:

A few minutes after posting this, I found a solution but not a reason why this happens (so I'm keeping the question open).

Instead of calling

```
p1 = plt.plot(X[pos,0], X[pos,1], marker='+', markersize=9, color='k')[0]
p2 = plt.plot(X[neg,0], X[neg,1], marker='o', markersize=7, color='y')[0]
```

I called the following, a lot more like in the original octave/matlab script:

```
pd.plotData(X[:,1:3],y)
```

the plotData function contains the exact same previous two `plt.plot(...)` lines. So, even though the code was identical, this healthier (less repetitive) way of plotting did the trick and the data points no longer align to x=1. Any thoughts on why this happens are welcome!

[image: data points properly plotted]

Comment: I'd guess it's a mistake in the plotting process that leads to weird results. Can you add a link to the data and code you use? The only possible mistake I see from you question is `u` and `v` should probably be from `np.meshgrid(x, y)` in contour. There are examples of contour/scatter (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431441/matplotlib-scatter-plot-to-foreground-on-top-of-a-contour-plot) which may be a good starting point (to see if bug in your version of `matplotlib` and build up to your example.

Comment: thanks @EdSmith! I updated the question since now I get the correct behavior changing the code a bit, but I'm still not positive why. You can take a look at the code at http://git.io/vZyso

Comment: It is hard to test without sample data.

Comment: @TheBlackCat all the code and data is in my previous comment!

Comment: The implicit usage of objects might be an issue here. I recommend getting used to the axes object in python. You can create an axes explicitly using `fig = mp.figure()` and `ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])` and plot your data directly into the new axis `ax.plot(...)` and `ax.contour(...)`.